# Mapping Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

say I created a dictionary,

```
 urlpar= {
        'd':'%s',
        'e':'%s',
        'f':'%s',
        'a':'%s',
        'b':'%s',
        'c':'%s',
        's':'%s'
        }
```

basically, i have string values, "1","2","3"..."6" which need to be filled into the dictionary at runtime. How can be do that ?

EDIT:
That means , i want to fit "1" to "d" , 2 to "e" and so on. The order must be there. 
thanks

thanks

Comment: Python dictionaries have no ordering; you'll need to *map* those values to dictionary keys by specifying an ordering *yourself*. What order do you need?

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? What happened? What did you *expect* to happen? What error messages, if any, did you get instead?

Comment: You just create the dictionary in the runtime!

Comment: You already seem to know a way to initialize dictionaries with string values so what are you even having trouble with?

Comment: @LakshmanPrasad: What if the OP needed to insert values at runtime and the format strings were a little more involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the keys in a list ('d','e','f',...), and also your desired values ('1','2','3',...), you can do:

```
>>> a=('d','e','f')
>>> b=('1','2','3')
>>> dict(zip(a,b))
{'e': '2', 'd': '1', 'f': '3'}
```

Comment: how are you even sure if that's what she's asking?

Comment: That's what I understand she's asking... If she clarifies and I was wrong I'd edit

Comment: Why not just wait, or not answer at all? This is a terrible question, as it stands, taking potshots at answering it are not going to go anywhere.

Comment: I figured trying to answer and get the chance of helping the OP is better than not answering... Don't you think so? (I'll remove the answer if that's what you all think)

Comment: If it isn't, just edit your question so we understand better